# Organizing page functions and page state using the Module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I'm developing a webpage using MVC which will be mainly JavaScript driven.

Instead of using global variables, and global functions, I would like to do it right this time. I don't want to use something to complex, because the team and I are new to large JavaScript applications. I tried implementing the Module pattern to organize my functions and page state.

This is what I came up with so far.

Am I misusing the Module pattern? What am I doing wrong? Where will I get into trouble?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ui = (function ($) {
        var _ui = {};

        _ui.submitMainForm = function () {                
            document.main.submit();
        };

        return _ui;
    } (jQuery));

    ui.tabs = (function ($) {
        var _tabs = {};

        var resourceTabs = $("#resourceTabs");
        var selectedTabPersistence = $("#SelectedTab");

        _tabs.getSelectedTab = function () {
            return selectedTabPersistence.val();
        };
        _tabs.setSelectedTab = function (value) {
            selectedTabPersistence.val(value);
        };
        _tabs.initialize = function () {
            resourceTabs.tabs({
                select: function (event, ui) { _tabs.setSelectedTab(ui.tab.hash); }
            });
            resourceTabs.tabs("select", _tabs.getSelectedTab());                
        };

        return _tabs;
    } (jQuery));

    ui.filter = (function ($) {
        var _filter = {};

        var personLevels = $("#personLevels");
        var vehicleLevels = $("#vehicleLevels");
        var personLevelsRadio = $("#personLevels :radio");
        var vehicleLevelsRadio = $("#vehicleLevels :radio");

        _filter.initialize = function () {
            personLevels.buttonset();
            vehicleLevels.buttonset();
            personLevelsRadio.bind("change", function () { ui.submitMainForm() });
            vehicleLevelsRadio.bind("change", function () { ui.submitMainForm() });
        };

        return _filter;
    } (jQuery));


    $(document).ready(function () {
        ui.tabs.initialize();
        ui.filter.initialize();
    });       
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple anonymous functions when you could do one and on the last line return your ui.* object.

```
var ui = (function($) {
    // local ui ref
    var ui = {};

    // other namespaces .. etc
    ui.tabs = {};

    return ui;
})(jQuery));
```